# what is the replacement for debug function in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
julia> debug("hello")
ERROR: UndefVarError: debug not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1
```

even tried with docker can't find suitable replacement.

```
help?> debug
search: @debug

Couldn't find debug
Perhaps you meant @debug, @enum, big or detach
  No documentation found.

  Binding debug does not exist.
```

Comment: https://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/debugging/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`@debug`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.3/stdlib/Logging/#Logging.@logmsg) macro to print debug output.

You have to enable debug output for you to actually see it. You can enable it with the env variable `JULIA_DEBUG`:

```
julia> @debug "hello"

julia> ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "all"
"all"

julia> @debug "hello"
┌ Debug: hello
└ @ Main REPL[4]:1
```